# Django validate email in Registration Form

Tags: python, html, django

Is there a way to validate email format in registration of account in Django?

I would like to allow users to only use gsfe accounts as their email when they are going to register in the app.

Comment: If registration means create new object of `User` model, just add validation inside `create` method. Also validation may be added to `UserSerializer` to check request data at API level

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `UserSerializer` to check data, something like:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
```

You can also [use Django Forms to create your registration form](https://www.csestack.org/django-sign-up-registration-form/).